# V-Play TabControl to bottom in Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, v-play

I am trying to work with V-Play App QML control and to use very usual design pattern like tabs with pages. I started with a snippet from official doc page https://v-play.net/doc/vplayapps-tabcontrol/

```
 Page {
   TabControl {
     NavigationItem {
       title: "Tab #1"
       icon: IconType.arrowleft

       FirstPage { }
     }
     NavigationItem {
       title: "Tab #2"
       icon: IconType.arrowright

       SecondPage { }
     }
   }
 }
```

And I am absolutely discouraged with the question: how to put tab control to the bottom of screen on Android?

If it is really impossible, does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tabPosition` property and set it to `Qt.BottomEdge`, like:

```
TabControl {
  tabPosition: Qt.BottomEdge

  NavigationItem {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

https://v-play.net/doc/vplayapps-tabcontrol-members/